# regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a tag like below:

```
<p id="questionText"><span class="qn" id="qn"> 1 </span>  hello? * </p>
```

I want to get the text(`"Hello"`) from that.

I've done that successfully with following code, but `.textContent` is not working in IE

```
 questionText = $('questionText-').textContent;
 questionText = questionText.replace(/\d+/g,"");
 questionText = questionText.replace("*","");
 return questionText.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'') ;
```

How can I change the code, so that it works in both?

Comment: `$('questionText-')` is not a valid selector. You probably wanted to use `$('#questionText')` if you are usin jQuery or `$('questionText')` if `$` is just aliasing `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you ses jquery framework. i think yo should use `.text()` or `.html()`

http://api.jquery.com/text/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

good luck

Comment: Thanks, but i want in javascript itself

Comment: Not really understand what you want. in javascript itself??

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `hello? *` part instead of the whole `1 hello? *` would be much better. To do this, we need to get the second child node of #questionText:

```
var qt = $("#questionText")[0];
qt.normalize();
var hello = qt.childNodes[1].data;
alert(hello); // outputs "  hello? * "
```

Now we can filter the string for unwanted characters like this,

```
hello = hello.
            replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").
            trim();
alert(hello); // outputs "hello"
```

All that's left is to capitalize the first letter.